# ngtable paging and sorting

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I have the following problem using ngtable. When I make a http get request and I get data, everything works fine with ngtable, but it gives me no the possibility to order. But if I make a new http get request (without reload page). Then show me the table with the new data, shows me correctly the amount of data of the new request, but does not show paging and not the option to select the number of rows per page. I tryed reload table params, without result.

My code:

```js
    $scope.httpget = function(uri)
    {
        $scope.data=[];
        $http.get(uri).then(
            function(result){
              $scope.data = result.data;
              $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                        page: 1,
                        count: 10,
                        filter: {
                            message: ''
                        },
                        sorting: {
                            timestamp: 'asc'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        getData: function($defer, params) {
                            var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                                $filter('orderBy')($scope.data, params.orderBy()) :
                                $scope.data;

                            params.total(orderedData.length);
                            $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                        }
                    });
            }
        );
    }
```

```html
<table ng-table='tableParams'>
    <tr ng-repeat='d in $data | filter:search'>
         <td data-title="'Collected Timestamp'" sortable="'timestamp'"> {{d.timestamp}} </td>
         <td data-title="'Tag Name'", sortable="'tag_name'"> {{d.tag_name}} </td>
         <td data-title="'Value'", sortable="'value'"> {{d.value}} </td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Result ok after first http get
[image]

Result bad after second http get (no paging)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happened with me as well. The problem I diagnosed was repeated initialization of `ng-table` instance.
You need to place the initialization of `ng-table` into separate function.(in my case, it was `init()`)

In your code, it should be something like this:

```
    $scope.data = [];

    init();
    function init() {
        $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
            page: 1,
            count: 10,
            filter: {
                message: ''
            },
            sorting: {
                timestamp: 'asc'
            }
        },{
            getData: function ($defer, params) {
                var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                    $filter('orderBy')($scope.data, params.orderBy()) :
                    $scope.data;

                params.total(orderedData.length);
                $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
            }
       });
    };
$scope.httpget = function (uri) {
    $http.get(uri).then(function (result) {
        $scope.data = result.data;
        $scope.tableParams.total($scope.data.length);
        $scope.tableParams.reload();
    }
  );
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Have you used

```
$scope.tableParams.total(data.length)
```

and

```
$scope.tableParams.reload();
```

at any point? How exactly do you 'do another get request'? Try uploading your code if it doesn't help

Comment: Thank you, your post gave me the idea. I took the "$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams" and put off the function that makes the http GET request, in that function only update the data.length and recharge the tableParams. I only wonder why it does not work the ordering. I put one point for you.